# Dropping two values in a dependent variable of a regression in R

Tags: r

If my y value for the regression has four values in the entire data (996, 997, 998, 999), I want to eliminate two values (996 and 999) when regressing on other variables. It is originally a Tobit, but for this sake I need to do a regular OLS regression. If you refer to the picture, essentially, I want to only consider the values that are valid (211). I'm not sure how to do this in R.

[image]

Comment: Do you have example code or dataset? This sounds like a simple subsetting problem.

Comment: Looks like that would leave only 8 cases. Doesn't seem wise.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have "smoke_data" as your data table, and "value" as response variable, here is a quick way to exclude unwanted value.

```
lm(value~.,data=smoke_data[smoke_data[,"value"]!=996 & smoke_data[,"value"]!=999, ])
```